# RichTextBox scroll to end not working when not visible

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, scrollbar, richtextbox, vertical-scrolling

I have a WPF RichTextBox in my application that sits in Grid. It gets updated every second or two as it displays logs (though sometimes there are no logs for up to a minute depending on the load).

The grid is not always visible, as it sits in its own tab. If the user is on another tab, the logger is not visible.

My problem is that I want the RichTextBox to scroll to the end every time a new paragraph is added. It seemed simple as there is a 'ScrollToEnd' method on the RichTextBox control and so I call that method every time text is added to the control.

The problem is that that method only works if the control is visible, if the user is on another tab, the RichTextBox will not scroll to the end and it looks weird when you click on the tab with the logger and after a couple of seconds or longer it scrolls to the bottom when it should already be at the bottom.

Is there a way around this annoying "feature" of the control? I would like to ALWAYS have the RichTextBox be at the bottom unless the user is manually taking control of the scroll bar.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, the TabControl actually doesn't change its contents visibility, it removes them from the view completely when you change tabs and then "re-attachs" them when you navigate back to the previous tab.

That's why the Visibility change doesn't get fired. Instead, you should handle the **Loaded** event, which should get fired right before the view is re-rendered.

Comment: This perfectly fixed my problem, now that I have hooked on to the loaded event everything is perfect! I can't believe I never thought of this, I was assuming it changing visibility and not being removed and added again. Bounty awarded.

Comment: It's pretty counterintuitive and not really well documented :P We found out the hard way too, after lots of trial and error and finally resorting to Snoop to check the visual tree - Finding that only the content of one TabItem was being rendered each time! (thanks for the bounty :)

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you cannot simply call `ScrollToEnd` in response to the text box becoming visible? That seems like the simplest approach. Did you try it and run into an issue?

Edit: If you are using a `TabControl`, each `TabItem` has an [IsSelected](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.tabitem.isselected.aspx) property you can bind to from the `ItemContainerStyle`. You could probably scroll your text box in response to the tab becoming selected.

---

As a separate note: if you are planning to make a custom control for this, here are some things to consider.

I wrote an auto-scrolling version of a `FlowDocumentScrollViewer`. (I never needed a `RichTextBox` specifically, but they display similar content.) I can tell you that there are a lot of things to account for, such as knowing when and when not to auto-scroll based on what the user is currently doing.

For example:

- If the user takes over the scrolling themselves via the scrollbar or mousewheel, you don't want the control to fight with them.
- If they start selecting text, you don't want to scroll it away from them mid selection.
- If they scroll to the bottom, you probably want it to start auto-scrolling again.

Also, determining what the user is doing to begin with can sometimes be a complex process on its own.

Comment: I tried to hook into the visible changing event however it did not fire when it became visible once the user went to a different tab and came back. I tried every event on there and I could not find one that always fired when the event was visible / rendered again.

I do not want to make a custom control, its more of "If I have too" kind of thing. I would much prefer to just find another solution that allows me to use the current control.

Comment: If you are using a `TabControl`, each `TabItem` has an [IsSelected](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.tabitem.isselected.aspx) property you can bind to from the `ItemContainerStyle`. You could probably scroll your text box in response to the tab becoming selected.

Comment: We use something similar, not the regular TabItem / TabControl but close enough. That does give me a good idea though for something to try, that I for what ever reason never thought about before. If it works I will accept your answer. The answer it self even if it is not my exact solution I think is still a good answer other people could use / see in the future.